# How to find equivalent filter

Tags: image-processing, convolution, imagefilter

I am stuck in my homework about convolution filters. I ofcourse don't want to know the answer but I want some guidance on how to maybe solve it. The question is given 2 kernels (k1 and k2), how to find an equivalent filter that would apply the effects of both the filters on an image.

Comment: Read here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170534/proof-of-associativity-of-convolution

Comment: Thank you, will look into it :-)